# Menu hamburger javascript doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, hamburger-menu

what is wrong with this code? Icons don't change after click and there is no contents after reveal menu. There are no errors in console.

```js
const nav_ = document.querySelector('nav');
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const burgerIco = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');
const closeIco = document.querySelector('.fa-times');

const active_toggle = function() {
  nav_.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('active');

  if (burger.classList.contains('active')) {
    burgerIco.classList.add('hide');
    closeIco.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    burgerIco.classList.remove('hide');
    closeIco.classList.add('hide');
  }
};

burger.addEventListener('click', active_toggle);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --color: rgb(175, 43, 19);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #ff4e00 0%, #ec9f05 74%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 350px;
  left: -350px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #bf033b 0%, #ffc719 74%);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.active {
  transform: translateX(350px)
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d3cc5ed543.js"></script>
<button class="burger">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-times hide"></i>
</button>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Produkty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

edit. i removed dots, now content is ok but icons still don;t change

Comment: please share jsfiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pL5u9b1m/

Comment: @AbdulBasitPlease do not ask for external code representations. This can, and **should** be done **within** StackOverflow.

Comment: @Monfear this is because your `.hide` css is overwritten please make it important or add css like this 
`i.hide {
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `.hide` css is overwritten please make it important or add css like `i.hide {//css}`

```js
const nav_ = document.querySelector('nav');
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const burgerIco = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');
const closeIco = document.querySelector('.fa-times');

const active_toggle = function() {
  nav_.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('active');

  if (burger.classList.contains('active')) {
    burgerIco.classList.add('hide');
    closeIco.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    burgerIco.classList.remove('hide');
    closeIco.classList.add('hide');
  }
};

burger.addEventListener('click', active_toggle);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --color: rgb(175, 43, 19);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #ff4e00 0%, #ec9f05 74%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 350px;
  left: -350px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #bf033b 0%, #ffc719 74%);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.active {
  transform: translateX(350px)
}

i.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d3cc5ed543.js"></script>
<button class="burger">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-times hide"></i>
</button>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Produkty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```